# moving "logic" out of dataaccess layer would lead to lots of database connections

Tags: java, data-access-layer

I have a method in my dataaccess layer that processes a file import. Such a file can have many records in it that need to be inserted into the database.
This method already contains certain "logic or business rules" and more need to be added.
Problem is if I move this out of the dataaccess layer each record would have to be inserted separately with a new connection. Obviously that is not very good when inserting thousands of records. (there is no guarantee that connections are pooled).
So I'm kind of lost on how to solve this. The dataaccess layer class is getting bigger and bigger and in term of good design os probably violating several rules already.

Only thing that comes to my mind is producer-consumer -> business logic imports file and performs validation and puts validated records into a queue. A separate thread (the dataaccess layer) reads from that queue.

Any other ideas? is there a pattern for such problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a design problem. The business logic layer should be the one demarcating transactions, and the data access layer should always use the same connection for a given transaction.

You could be using Spring, for example, which would let you use declarative transactions and a connection pool, and would make sure the same connection is used for the whole transaction.

Comment: So the business layer can contain JDBC code withput breaking certain principles? This is for a rather samll and simple thing so I do wish to avoid "large enterprise libraries".

Comment: No. The business layer should start a transaction (declaratively), call the data access layer to get/store/find business objects, and implement the business logic on those business objects. Every database interaction should be done in the DAL. Using a spring transaction manager and spring's jdbc helper classes is not as heavy/enterprisy as you might think.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a separte business layer separate from dataaccess layer - here deal with your business rules , and when you are ready to call into data-access , create collection of business objects - pass then into the DA layer - the DA  layer will process the objects - either as individual rows or as a single bulk operation -
2. Use Design patterns in your business layer that will keep the evolution simple.

Comment: Can't pass all objects at once into the DA Layer because of memory consumption. The object are ultra heavy weight. while most of them time it will be ok, in some it will not and hence I have to be prepared for that case.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "Cant' pass .. because objects are heavy" - Passing objects into another layer is not impacted by how heavy the objects are - you are passing the References - not creating clones of them.

Comment: What I mean is if i have a large amount of data, I can't have it all in memory. If for example the input is a file i would have to process each record (or a set of records) individually and pass them on to the DA Layer for saving. Of course I then can't have the whole process in the same transaction at least with plain JDBC.